# How to get youtube video views from youtube video player in Android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

How can i get **total video views & likes** of the youtube video from youtube player api in android?

Answer (score 1):

```
When you see the JSON, Under the statistics part you have viewCount.

which gives you the number of views. 

"items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": etag,
   "id": string,
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": unsigned long,
    "likeCount": unsigned long,
    "dislikeCount": unsigned long,
    "favoriteCount": unsigned long,
    "commentCount": unsigned long
   }
  }
]

Hope it helps
```

Comment: Here i am not doing any JSON Parsing. I just have the link of the video and i am playing the video in my app (via Youtube player). So i am not sure how to apply your solution in my case.